# The used command is not allowed again

Tags: mysql, r, window, mysql-workbench

Windows 10/MySQL8.0/R/RStudio

I'm running MySQL as a Windows service.

I've read a couple of related post on this site the evening.
I created my.cnf file as suggested:

```
[mysql]
local-infile
```

I've the cnf file in The same directory as the exec., in the MySQL/etc directory, in my home directory and finally in C:\

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The key to resolving this issue is that I'm running MySQL as a Windows service. Windows services are managed by the **services.msc** program.

MySQL entry in services manager:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"
```

All we have to do is in the **my.ini** (remember in Windows config files are *.ini):

```
[mysqld]=1

local-infile=1
```